# How to build a linear regression model and apply it on DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

For various points in my landscape I have sampled their elevation (z) and information (i). Now I want to build a regression model (linear) to predict i from the elevation and apply it on my digital elevation model (DEM). My aim is to produce a continuous map of i.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS? The only way I can think of is to export the points to R (or Excel), build my linear regression model, export the equation and use it with the raster calculator.  Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: I think doing this in R would make the most sense. You can do this in SAGA, Grass, or R but, if you already know how to use R, just use that

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is how iam going to try it then. I will update this post with comment on how it went,